# composer not installing latest facebook php sdk due to multiple php versions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, composer-php

I'm trying to load the latest php sdk for facebook but I am getting errors with composer. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

```
{
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
  }
}
```

> ```
> [root@gridjungle gridjungle]# composer update
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.8 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.7 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.6 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.5 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>     - Installation request for facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.* -> satisfiable by facebook/php-sdk-v4[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4,
> ```
>
> 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.8].
>
> ```
> Potential causes:
>  - A typo in the package name
>  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>    see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion>
> ```
>
> for more details.
>
> ```
> Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
> [root@gridjungle gridjungle]# composer install
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update
> ```
>
> to update them.
>       Nothing to install or update
>       Generating autoload files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 4+ of the PHP SDK requires PHP 5.4+.

If you cannot upgrade your PHP version, you'll have to use the older SDK, "facebook/php-sdk"

edit by Clint C.: Fosco was right. Due to having multiple versions of PHP installed I had to specify which version for composer to use. To do this though I had to install composer locally in my project location and not use the globally installed version.

```
/usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin/php composer.phar update
```

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.5.12

Comment: the error message you provided strongly suggests otherwise.  perhaps multiple versions are installed and composer is using a different one.  you can try executing composer with the right version, i.e. /usr/local/bin/php composer.phar install

Comment: I do have multiple versions. I have a DV server from media temple. My other sites run an older version of PHP. This is the only site on the server running. 5.5.12. Is there a way of letting composer know that?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my last comment, use the full path to the right version of PHP to execute composer.

Comment: Nope... just invoke it through the right version of php from the command line.

Comment: I tried running the command /usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin composer install but get this message -bash: /usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin: is a directory

Comment: yeah.. bin is a directory.. is there a php file in there? i.e. /usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin/php ?

Comment: [root@gridjungle gridjungle]# /usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin/php composer install
Could not open input file: composer

Comment: when i installed it i first ran "cd /var/www/vhosts/furkidgrid.com/gridjungle" then after install i did "mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" could this be the problem?

Comment: then it sounds like you need to use `/usr/local/bin/composer` instead of just `composer` after your php executable.

Comment: Fosco, sorry for all the questions. I'm completely ignorant with linux etc. Here's what I ran `code[root@gridjungle gridjungle]# /usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer install
Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: The problem was because I installed it globally. I removed composer from bin and re-downloaded it to my project file and then ran the following command and everything worked great. `code /usr/local/php-5.5.13-cgi/bin/php composer.phar update`